# Need of executable stack and heap memory

Tags: c, security, memory, buffer-overflow

As we know that making the stack and the heap area of the virtual memory non-executable can prevent the execution of malicious code (like a shellcode) inside the memory (the technique is called [Data Execution Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention)). And, the simplest way to inject the malicious code inside the memory is by overflowing the buffer. Thus, making these areas of the memory non-executable can help in reducing the severity of overflow attacks.

However, there are many other techniques like address space randomization, pointer protection, use of canaries etc. that are used to prevent such attacks. I think most of the system make use of these other methods instead of making the stack/heap memory non-executable.(Please correct me if I am wrong here)

Now, my question is, are there some specific operations or special cases in which the stack/heap parts of memory are required to be executable?

Comment: JIT is easily implemented if the heap is executable. Not sure how it's done in general, though.

Comment: Trampoline code for [GCC's nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) need an executable stack AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

JITs map writeable and executable regions of memory or simply `mprotect` previously allocated memory to make it executable.

GCC used to require an a system dependent method to mark parts of the stack executable for their trampoline code. This was 12 years ago though, I don't know how it's done today.

Dynamic linking on many systems also needs an ability to write to a jump table for function calls resolved during run time. If you want to have the jump table non-writeable between updates to the table that can be quite costly.

Generally it's possible to solve those problems safely by trying to enforce a policy where memory is writeable or executable, but never both. Memory can be remapped to be writeable when the write needs to be done and then protected again to make it executable. It trades off some performance (not that much) for better security and slightly more complex code.